# "TypeError: visible.map is not a function" when toggling button

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, toggle

Trying to render a list in React. I want each button to toggle visibility of a component with some content (this is going to be a reel of projects). I get the list rendered just as I expect it to, but whenever I click one of the buttons, I get "TypeError: visible.map is not a function". The code worked when I rendered each component individually, but when I introduced the state and .map, suddenly we stopped being friends...

Parent:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import ExampleOne from './Examples/exampleOne.js';
import ExampleTwo from './Examples/exampleTwo.js';
import ExampleThree from './Examples/exampleThree.js';

function SectionTwo() {

     const [visible, setVisible] = useState([
        { number: 1, content: < ExampleOne setVisible = { visible => setVisible(visible => !visible)} />, visible: false },
        { number: 2, content: < ExampleTwo setVisible = { visible => setVisible(visible => !visible)} />, visible: false },
        { number: 3, content: < ExampleThree setVisible = { visible => setVisible(visible => !visible)} />, visible: false }
    ]);
 
    return ( 

        <div className="section-content seciton2">
            <p>We're no strangers to love<br/>
            You know the rules and so do I<br/>
            A full commitment's what I'm thinking of<br/>
            You wouldn't get this from any other guy<br/>
            I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling<br/>
            Gotta make you understand</p>

            
                    {visible.map((i) => (
                <ul className="examples"
                    onClick={() => setVisible(visible => !visible)}
                    key={i.number}
                >
                    <button className={ 'example' + i.number } onClick={() => setVisible(visible => !visible)}></button>
                </ul>
                ))}
                

        </div>

    );
  }

export default SectionTwo;
```

Children:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function ExampleThree(props) {

    let exampleRef = useRef();

    useEffect (() => {
        let handler = (event) => {
            if (!exampleRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            props.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler)
        }
    });



    return ( 
  
        <div className="example3-content" ref={exampleRef}>

            <p>We're no strangers to love<br/>
            You know the rules and so do I<br/>
            A full commitment's what I'm thinking of<br/>
            You wouldn't get this from any other guy<br/>
            I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling<br/>
            Gotta make you understand</p>
            
            <button onClick={() => props.setVisible(visible => !visible)}>ha det</button>

        </div>

    );
  }

export default ExampleThree;
```

(Never mind the placeholder text, I'm just tired of Lorem Ipsum...)

Comment: your visible is a Array when you init, but why you add the `onClick={() => setVisible(visible => !visible)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setVisible(visible => !visible)`

This code piece probably doesn't do what you think. Initially you have an array of objects set to the state named `visible`. When you negate it, it just becomes `false`. Therefore, it cannot invoke the `map` function on a state with a value `false`.

Comment: You are completely right. I was actually hiding the whole state and breaking everything - thanks!
I just left the thought of managing things through state and put in different keys in each child element + their buttons. It works well enough :)

Answer (score 0):

There're so many problems in this code and I didn't really understand what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm not going to try to improve it. But I'll do a quick code-review and give you some suggestions;

- I'd suggest you should never change the type of a state element (in this example, visible changes from array to boolean, which causes the error)
- You should also avoid declarative programming, means you should avoid useRef if you're not sure what you're doing
- I'd co-locate the state where it belongs (visibility state of a component belongs to the component itself not the parent component)
- You should use JSX over JSON where applicable, that means I'd never use an array to map over instead I'd use the power of JSX and wrote those "content"s directly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @Eusbolh pointed out what I needed to be pointed out.
You did a good technical recap on what was breaking my code (state, state type, etc)! :)

When it comes to useRef, I'm using it to enable hiding the content by clicking outside of it, and when it comes to usage of JSON, I did it because I wanted to use a map (which was a bad idea). My solution was to use JSX to fix my problem, and the useRef is still doing its amazing job :)